# How to customize navigation bar title font and size in UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to customize only a specific part of the navigation bar title.

For example, "Navigation Bar Title." I made this sentence a title.

In the case of "Navigation", apply blue color and system bold font,
For "Bar Title." I want to apply red color and system regular fonts.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `UILabel` with an attributed title as a custom title view for your navigation bar.

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()

//attributes for the first part of the string  
let firstAttr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                                .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]

//attributes for the second part of the string  
let secondAttr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                                 .foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

//initializing and merging the two parts
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Navigation", attributes: firstAttr)
let secondAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: " Bar Title", attributes: secondAttr)
attrString.append(secondAttrString)

//setting the attributed string as an attributed text
titleLabel.attributedText = attrString

//set the size of the label to fit its contents
titleLabel.sizeToFit()

//setting the label as the title view of the navigation bar
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

**Result:**

[image: navigation bar with custom title view]

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

NSDictionary *settings = @{
    UITextAttributeFont                 :  [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOURFONTNAME" size:20.0],
    UITextAttributeTextColor            :  [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor      :  [UIColor clearColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset     :  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetZero]};

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:settings];
```

Comment: thank you. your answer is clean However, the above answer was a little more understandable.

Comment: Yes obviously above will serve you better two problems: 1. New Control UILabel created will result in consumption of memory 2. If you have 100 view controller then 100 new label will be created and assigned to title view

Comment: I did not think about that. I think you are right.
But your code is so unfamiliar to me. Is swift right?

Comment: Swift:
        
        
        let settings = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "YOURFONTNAME", size: 20.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20),
                              NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white
            ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]